# How can i make my solr search case sensitive?

Tags: views, search

I am using [search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [search api solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module,
currently my search is case insensitive with following configration.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="query">
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

if i remove `<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>` it becomes case sensitive.
How can i have both the thing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519122/solr-search-query-case-sensitiveness

Comment: @mks you want it to be both case-sensitive and not case-sensitive? Can you clarify?

Comment: yes, both case-sensitive and case insensitive.

Comment: That's not possible. Case insensitive ignores capitals while case sensitive only matches on capitals. You can't have both.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to add a search option for case sensitive or not?  As Patrick mentions, it is not possible to both search case sensitive and case insensitive at the same time.  That is like turning left and right at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Original answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205688/how-to-make-field-search-not-case-sensitive-in-solr-using-solrnet

You could use a copyfield that converts the field in question to lowercase.

Similar problem/solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053214/how-to-create-a-case-insensitive-copy-of-a-string-field-in-solr